Cursor not appearing after pressing Enter in custom Tiptap extension with HardBreak
I have created a custom Tiptap extension to add a line break <br> when pressing the Enter key. The extension works as expected by inserting a <br> tag. However I'm encountering an issue where the cursor does not appear in the new line immediately after pressing Enter.
After pressing the Enter key, a <br> tag is inserted, and the cursor appears to move to the next line. However the blinking cursor doesn't show up on the new line until I start typing. The cursor is visible on the current line when typing, but after pressing Enter, it disappears, making it difficult for the user to immediately see where they can start typing
Can anyone help me fix this issue or suggest why the cursor is not appearing right after the line break?
Thx :)
import {HardBreak} from "@tiptap/extension-hard-break";

const Linebreak = HardBreak.extend({
    group: 'block',
    content: 'inline*',
    inline: false,
    addCommands() {
        return {
            setLineBreak: () => ({ commands, editor }) => {
                const { state } = editor;
                const { selection } = state;
                const { $head } = selection;
                const position = $head.after();

                commands.insertContentAt({ from: position, to: position }, { type: this.name });
                return true;
            }
        };
    },

    addKeyboardShortcuts() {
        return {
            'Enter': () => {
                return this.editor.commands.setLineBreak();
            },
        };
    }
});

export { Linebreak, Linebreak as default };

I tried to add a new Paragraph after adding the br-tag but this did not help

If the cursor is placed in the right position, meaning when you start typing you get the text in the right position, it might just be some css issue. I had an issue with the cursor not appearing some time ago, and I ended up setting a min-width of 1px to the  element and that solved it. Try to inspect the HTML, maybe you have the same issue.
